# Cat with scar from unknown source

Tags: cats

Our cat has a scar from an unknown source.  We don't think she has been in any kind of fight or accident (she is always in an apartment and only has access to a balcony).  We also think it is getting worse, it has been there for around a week.  There was no red patch previously, just a tuft of missing hair.  She does not seem to be in pain.

We are getting an appointment with our vet as soon as possible, the red patch has alarmed us.  But does anybody know what this is, if it is not from a fight with another cat?

UPDATE: We took her to the vet and it turns out that she has an allergy and has been scratching it herself.  They gave us a sort of body suit that she now has to wear for 10 days to allow it to heal.  Plus an injection to stop the itching.

[image: Cat scar]

Comment: From the looks of it, it could be from another cat, but it could be from wildlife as well.  It's not impossible for larger birds to target cats, which could reach her on a balcony, though that would be pretty unusual. But, has she been itching their prior to the red patch appearing?

Comment: Thanks @Timmy Jim.  I think the itching is a very good suggestion.  We have not noticed it but indeed she could be doing it to herself.  We will post the real answer when we get her to the vet.

Comment: @Timmy Jim   It was indeed an allergy and she had been scratching herself.

Comment: Good job cat parents!

Answer (score 4):

Going to the vet soon is a great plan.

It could be ringworm [(*Dermatophytosis*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermatophytosis) which can be transmitted between pets, people and other pets.

Until you get a definitive diagnosis from you vet, you may want to assume it is contagious.

Prevention (source is [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermatophytosis#Prevention)):

> Advice often given includes:
>
> Avoid sharing clothing, sports equipment, towels, or sheets.
>
> Wash clothes in hot water with fungicidal soap after suspected exposure to ringworm.
>
> Avoid walking barefoot; instead wear appropriate protective shoes in locker rooms and sandals at the beach.
>
> Avoid touching pets with bald spots, as they are often carriers of the fungus.

Comment: Thanks James, it  turns out it was an allergy and that she had been scratching herself.  I appreciate the advice you've given, will bear that in mind for the future.